# Why the setting of a margin results in two different values on desktop and mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, window

I have a set of `div`'s that should be vertically spaced from each other by the height of the window plus an extra space (`+ 100px`). However, when setting this margin in jQuery the margin is different for mobile browser and desktop browser, treating the additional `+ 100` as a string rather than a number.

**My Code**

```
$(".text-container").css("margin", "50px auto " + (window.innerHeight + 100) + "px auto")
```

**Resulting margin on *DESKTOP*** *(Chrome)*

```
alert((window.innerHeight + 100) + ", " + typeof (window.innerHeight + 100) + ", " + $(".text-container").css("margin")) 

--> 740, number, 50px 18px 740px
```

**Resulting margin on *MOBILE*** *(Chrome and Samsung Internet)*

```
alert((window.innerHeight + 100) + ", " + typeof (window.innerHeight + 100) + ", " + $(".text-container").css("margin")) 

--> 874, number, 50px 20.6094px 740100px 20.5938px
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well - this seems weird to me. I would create the offset outside the `.css()`, inside a variable, and then call it from inside the `.css()`.

Give it a go:

```
var add_margin = window.innerHeight + 100;
$(".text-container").css("margin", "50px auto "+add_margin+"px auto");
```

That should work.

What I usually do when numbers are interpreted as strings rather than floats (or integers), try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` functions to tell the browser what type of data that a variable contains.